# Flex and zendamf on server - class not found

Tags: apache-flex, zend-framework, flex4.5, zend-amf

I am working on a flex php project where i am using zendamf to transfer remote messages.
I've installed Zend Framework. Everything works fine on localhost , but when i transfer the service php's to server , it says "class does not exists !!!"

My amf_config.ini file have these proerties:

```
 [zend]
webroot = /home/myserver/www 
zend_path = /home/myserver/www/ZendFramework/library


[zendamf]
amf.production = false
amf.directories[]=services
```

and the actionscript function which calls the remote class have these properties:

```
remoteObject.destination = "decoyDestination";
remoteObject.source = "serviceTest";
remoteObject.endpoint = "http://myserver.com/zendtest/gateway.php";
```

But it says the class does not exists !!

```
[RPC Fault faultString="Class "serviceTest" does not exist: Plugin by name 'ServiceTest' was not found in the registry; used paths:
: /home/myserver/www/zendtest/services/"
```

I'm out of ideas and really exhausted. Can anyone please help me ?

Comment: i've cornered out the problem and it seems the gateway.php can't autoload the classes i've put in my services folder. If i manually set the classes, everything works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved !!!
it seems zendamf tries to find a class for the given "method" like this:
if your source is given as "serviceTest"
the plugin loader of zendamf tries to find it's parent class by making the first character UPPERCASE. So in my case it was trying to load the class named "ServiceTest" which does't exists. So i made the first character of my .php file UPPERCASE and it works !!!

I hope it will help someone else who's in same difficulties :)